# How to save child Schema in mongodb using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Following is my order object that I am trying to save -

```
{ 
  shipper: 
     { firstName: 'Test ShipName',
       address1: '10 Florida Ave',
       phone1: '800-123-4567' },
    consignee: 
     { firstName: 'AAA Manufacturing',
       address1: '100 Main Street' },
    items: 
    [ 
      { length1: 45, weight1: 12, height1: 45, width1: 34 },
      { length2: 42, weight2: 34, height2: 90, width2: 54 }
    ]
}
```

On doing this -

```
        Order(order).save(function(err, result){
            if(err)
                throw err;
            console.log(result);
        });
```

shipper, consignee are saving appropriate values but in database(mongodb), items are not saving properly -

```
"items" : [
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("54e36e18c59700b513a5309d")
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("54e36e18c59700b513a5309c")
    }
],
```

Following is my `oderSchema` -

```
var orderSchema = mongoose.Schema ({
    shipper: {type: addressSchema, 'Default':''}},      
    consignee: {type: addressSchema, 'Default':''} },
    items: {type: [itemSchema], 'Default':''} },
});
```

Following is my **itemSchema** -

```
var itemSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  length: {type: Number, required: false },
  width: {type: Number, required: false },
  height: {type: Number, required: false }, 
  weight: {type: Number, required: false }, 
});
```

Let me know what I am doing wrong in saving the item info.

Comment: I cannot reproduce. Few obvious things: 1. you have syntax errors (too many closing brackets) in `orderSchema` definition. 2. after fixing that, I got: `TypeError: Undefined type at 'shipper' Did you try nesting Schemas? You can only nest using refs or arrays.`. What version of Mongoose are you using? Could you provide entire code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your itemSchema, the properties are "length", "width" etc, however properties of the data that you're saving contains numbers at the end "length1", "length2", etc. You need to remove those numbers.